# Mark numbers for sudoku game

Tags: java, sudoku

im currently programming a sudoku game in java. I created a 2 dimensional array as the playingfield. Now i want to write a method, which saves numbers for a given position in the playingfield, for example i want to save the numbers 9 and 4 at the position (3,5) in the field. I've thought about to create an array for the position and save the numbers there, i've tried that but i really dont know how to do it. I searched some sites for my problem but i couldnt find solution for it. I hope someone can help me with that.

```
public byte[][] sudoku = new byte[9][9];

public SudokuField(byte[][] sudoku){
    if(sudoku.length != 9){
        System.exit(2);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++){
        if(sudoku[i].length > 9){
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
    this.sudoku = sudoku;
}

public boolean checkColumn(int x, int y, byte value){
    boolean check = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.sudoku.length; i++){
        if(this.sudoku[i][y] == value){
            check = false;
        }
    }
    return check;
}

public boolean checkRow(int x, int y, byte value){
    boolean check = true;
    for(int i = x; i < x + 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < this.sudoku[i].length; j++){
            if(this.sudoku[i][j] == value){
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

public boolean checkSquare(int x, int y, byte value){
    boolean check = true;       
    x = (int)(x / 3) * 3;
    y = (int)(y / 3) * 3;
    for(int i = x; i < x + 3; i++){
        for(int j = y; j < y + 3; j++){
            if(this.sudoku[i][j] == value){
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}

public void setCell(int x, int y, byte value){
    if(x < 0 || x > 9 || y < 0 || y > 9){
        System.out.println("Invalid Number");
    }else if(checkRow(x,y, value) && checkColumn(x,y,value) && checkSquare(x, y, value)){
        this.sudoku[x][y] = value;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid cell");
    }
}

public byte getCell(int x, int y){
    return this.sudoku[x][y];
}

public void markCell(int x, int y, byte value){

}
```

So this is the code i wrote so far. Im currently working on markCell, which saves numbers at a position u might want to put into the position. So my idea is to create an array for the position, to store these numbers in it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already done? We'll have something to work with and we'll help you

Comment: maybe you can add more details to your question like code snippets?

Comment: Please be more specific, what problems exactly are you facing? Show us some code you've tried. "i want to save the numbers 9 and 4 at the position (3,5)" - as far as I know it is one number per cell, no?

Comment: Create a Cell class that holds a found number, a List of possible numbers, and a List of pencil mark numbers.  That way, you can display the possibilities appropriately.  Your Sudoku board would be a List or array of 81 Cell instances.

Comment: create an  ArrayList of your custom-defined class (say cell) ```ArrayList<Cell>();```
where the object of the cell contains **index, values** for your sudoku board